# Printing a custom representation of my own datatype in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, output, custom-data-type, haskell-prelude

### Context

Important detail, I am using Haskell (NOT CABAL) on [repl.it](https://replit.com/new/haskell). I would like to print a custom Haskell datatype that I created. I was thinking of an approach similar to Python's `__repr__` or `__str__` methods, when creating a new class. Something like:

```py
class Length:
    def __init__(self, value, unit_of_measurement):
        self.value = value
        self.unit_of_measurement = unit_of_measurement
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.value}{self.unit_of_measurement}'
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Which will produce the following:

```py
>>> # I can print a custom representation of the object
>>> l = Length(10, 'cm')
>>> l
10cm
>>> print(l)
10cm
```

### The problem

I am trying to instantiate the `Show` class in my custom datatype and use pattern matching to customize the output that will be sent to the console.

### What I tried so far

```hs
-- This works fine
data Length = Length {value :: Double, unit_of_measurement :: String}
    deriving (Eq, Ord)  -- I don't want to use default Show inheritance

-- These lines are actually wrong, but I don't know how to solve this
-- Also, how to get the fields declared in my datatype???
instance Show Length where  -- Or IO, I am not sure
    print Length = print $ show value ++ unit_of_measurement
```

**Ignoring the wrong lines** that I mentioned (so the compiler won't stop the execution) and **considering I have used Haskell's built-in inheritance mechanism** with `Show` (`deriving(Show)`) this will be the result, (which I don't like):

```hs
λ> :load Main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
λ> let test = Length 10 "cm"
λ> test
Length {value = 10.0, unit_of_measurement = "cm"}  -- HERE , THIS IS THE PROBLEM
```

I understand if it is not possible to do exactly what I want, but, is there any way to do something near this, or similar? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `Show` class in `base` corresponds to Python’s `__repr__` for “raw” debug output. There are multiple packages providing analogues of `__str__` for formatting human-readable output in different ways. I think the `Pretty` class in the [`prettyprinter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter) package is a good basic choice for most projects.

Comment: just a side note when you derive Ord you don't get the behaviour one would expect. try comparing `1cm < 1mm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method of the `Show` typeclass is called `show`, not `print`. You'll need to remove the call to `print`. The `show` function must return a plain `String`, not an `IO ()`.

To pattern match on a record as you have it, you can enable the `RecordWildCards` language extension by declaring it at the very top of the file, and then in the function definition use `Length{..}` to pattern match and bring all the fields of the record into scope.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

data Length = Length {value :: Double, unit_of_measurement :: String}
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Show Length where
    show Length{..} = show value ++ unit_of_measurement
```

Without that language extension, you could access the record fields in a few other ways:

```
show Length{value=v, unit_of_measurement=u} = show v ++ u

show (Length v u) = show v ++ u

show l = show (value l) ++ unit_of_measurement l
```

Comment: Thank you so much, great answer, btw! I have a question left, just for curiosity's sake: is there any other way to take the arguments without the language extension you showed me?

Comment: @NickS1 Yes, I've added those to my answer.

Comment: I think your answer should point out that calling [`show`][Show](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Text-Show.html#t:Show) should result in valid Haskell. Therefore `show` is probably not the correct approach.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, I am not sure if I get your point. This answer looks quite valid to me. Would you mind explaining better your point of view? What do you mean when you say: “Show should return in valid Haskell”?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Sure, but still I can’t understand. I think you should post an answer with your solution to better explain what you mean. You know, space gets tight here in comments. If you agree, of course.

Comment: @NickS1 I just meant to repeat what Jon Purdy said in a comment to the question. The result of calling `show` should look like Haskell code, so `Length {value = 10.0, unit_of_measurement = "cm"}` is morally correct but `"10.0 cm"` is not.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, now I get it! Thanks for your patience!